# problems with Facebook share button

Tags: facebook

The goal is to use facebook share button.

```
"App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions."
```

This is a message when I want to login with other than my app account. When I login with my app account I can use the button otherwise not. Is it because I use test apps delails? When I use my original website app id it gives the same message. In settings it is available to public. Test application is in development mode, it doesnt change to available to public. Should I remove test version or?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is in development and no one user can use this application except developers and organizers. You can see list of all people who can use your app at menu item "Roles" at application dashboard. To make your application available to other people make next steps:
Go to app dashboard at facebook -> Settings -> set contact email -> App Review -> swith first slider to YES position.
After this manipulations other people can login to your app correctly.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks a lot for the answer. it was turned to to yes. in my case the problem was carelessness. wrote wrong appid number:)